# How to remove mysterious border in string builder table?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, .net, stringbuilder

I have some code that generates a PDF. For some reason there is a black bordered cell showing up behind the image on this line:

```
sb.AppendLine("<tr><td>" + "~/images/Products/" + imageName + "</td><td>~/images/spacer.gif</td></tr>");
```

I have tried setting the border to 0 on the table, but I'm getting an error ") expected", or the html just breaks.

How can I ensure that there is no border shown around this cell?

Here are the two parts involved:

```
//add images
        str = new StringBuilder();
        str.Append("<table>");

        if (HasRelatedImages(ContentId, ref str))
        {
            obj = new List<FieldIdentifier>();
            obj.Add(new FieldIdentifier() { LabelName = "Images", Value = "" });
            index = index + 1;
            rows.Add(index, obj);

            obj = new List<FieldIdentifier>();
            obj.Add(new FieldIdentifier() { LabelName = "NewTable_Data", Value = str.Append("</table>").ToString() });
            index = index + 1;
            rows.Add(index, obj);
        }
        //end images
```

and

```
private Boolean HasRelatedImages(long productId, ref StringBuilder sb)
{
    var imagemetadata = new List<ImageMetadata>();
    int i = 0;

    try
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("Site.DbConnection");
        DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("[spSelectImages]");
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@ContentID", DbType.Int64, productId);
        IDataReader dr = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand);

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string imageName = GetNullableDBStringValue(dr["ImageName"]);
            string altText = GetNullableDBStringValue(dr["ALTText"]);
            altText = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(altText);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageName) && System.IO.File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/Products/" + imageName)))
            {
                i++;

                sb.AppendLine("<tr><td>" + i.ToString() + "</td><td>" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(altText) ? " " : altText) + "</td></tr>");
                sb.AppendLine("<tr><td>" + "~/images/Products/" + imageName + "</td><td>~/images/spacer.gif</td></tr>");
            }

        }
        dr.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }


    if (i > 0) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: could you please provide a plunkr with the issue that you are facing

Comment: Can you add the code where setting border to 0 caused an error?

Comment: str.Append("<table border="0">");

It was giving me a syntax error actually. I just don't know how I can change the border property here.

Comment: If I change it like str.Append("<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>"); then all the HTML just shows up and on the pdf.

Comment: did you try escaping the quotes? i.e. `str.Append("<table border=\"0\">");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was other code involved adding the border. No change was needed to this piece.